# React native my app wont show any results from API GET call

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, api

This is my code It is supposed to work but somehow it doesn't. I've also tried to use this JSON https://reactnative.dev/movies.json but I also get the same result

```
export default class App extends Component {
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    data: []
  }
}

componentDidmount() {
fetch('http://192.168.1.4:8080/api', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {

               data = result});
}



render() {

  return (
    <View>
      <Text 
        style = {{fontSize: 18}}>
        Display API JSON DATA
    </Text>
    <FlatList
    data = { this.state.data }
    renderItem= { ({item}) =>
    <View>
    <Text>{item.title}</Text>
    <Text>{ this.state.data }</Text>
    </View>

    }
    />
    </View>
  )
}


}
```

This is my JSON file

```
 [{"price":3,"_id":"5f32d2f3f995eb0013ff4be7","title":"new book","__v":0},]
```

the result is the following

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use `this.setState()` set your component states. [learn more](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

```js
componentDidmount() {
fetch('http://192.168.1.4:8080/api', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {
                   this.setState({data: result})
});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked doing console.log inside render before flatlist ? What does this.state.data contain